# Installing Spring Cloud Services for Cloudfoundry without OpsManager

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud

I've installed cloudfoundry on my local machine as described [here](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/run-local.html) and now I'd like to install Spring Cloud Services as well. However I don't know where to find OpsManager and I doubt if it is deployed at all. So the question is - is it possible to install Spring Cloud Services  without using OpsManager and if so, how to achieve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the PM for Spring Cloud Services.

The Spring Cloud Services product is only supported on a Pivotal Cloud Foundry installation, and depends on other Pivotal commercial products.

If you'd like to consume Spring Cloud on an OSS Cloud Foundry deployment, you'll need to create Spring Boot applications for the server-side components as described in the Spring Cloud OSS docs (http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html). An example of a GitHub project that does this can be found here: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/fortune-teller.